# Laravel Jobs and Telescope Package

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, telescope

I'm using the Telescope package in my Laravel app to monitor requests, and I have multiple jobs set up with the `queue_connection` configured to use the database.

here is how the job is added to the queue: `sendMassTextJob::dispatch($arr);`

and the issue is that the `php artisan queue:work` command works fine locally, but in my online version of the app, I observe that the job remains in a 'pending' status.

Have you ever encountered such an issue with Laravel jobs and the Telescope package? Do you have any advice on how to resolve this?